# Reduce the Execution time for a Postgres SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wrote a sql as below based on requirement which is giving right result but its taking around 7 secs

```
select 
  distinct m.mdl, m.src
from model m
join company c on c.name = m.name
  and c.partner = m.partner
where c.id = 1234
and m.status = 'ACTIVE'
EXCEPT 
select
  md.mdl,
  md.src
from model md 
right join (
    select
      distinct m.mdl, m.src
    from model m, company c
    where c.name = m.name
    and c.partner = m.partner 
    and c.id in (123,1122)
) t on md.mdl = t.mdl
  and md.src = t.src
join company cp on cp.name = md.name
  and cp.partner = md.partner
where cp.id = 1234
and md.status = 'ACTIVE'
```

Any suggestion to rewrite inorder to reduce the execution time in the above sql from 7 secs.

I tried writing SQL using WITH query which is giving the right result but taking around 30 secs.

Comment: This seems overly complex and can probably be greatly simplified. Cann you explain the logic you try to implement?

Comment: try changing `from model m, company c where c.name = m.name and c.partner = m.partner and c.id in (123,1122)` to `from model m join company c on c.name = m.name  and c.partner = m.partner and c.id in (123,1122)`. And I assume you have appropriate indexes defined?

Comment: @Bohemian Why should changing implicit to explicit join syntax change the plan?

Comment: @dnoeth without optimization, a `join` then a `where` executes the entire cartesean join *then* filters with the `where`, whereas conditions on the  `join` use indexes and filter as the join is made, vastly cutting down the temporary rowset size.  I have seen optimizers not get that conversion right.

Comment: @Bohemian I have seen optimizers not get that conversion right decades ago... PostgreSQL is not that stupid :-)

Comment: @Bohemian dnoeth is right, PostgreSQL handles that correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks like you try to get models with id 1234, but not ids 123&1122.

Those might return the same result:

```
select 
   m.mdl, m.src
from model m
join company c on c.name = m.name
  and c.partner = m.partner
where m.status = 'ACTIVE'
group by m.mdl, m.src
having count(case when c.id = 1234 then 1 end) = 1        -- 1234 exists
   and count(case when c.id in (123,1122) then 1 end) = 0 -- but not 123 or 1122

select 
  distinct m.mdl, m.src
from model m
join company c on c.name = m.name
  and c.partner = m.partner
where c.id = 1234
and m.status = 'ACTIVE'
AND NOT EXISTS
 ( select 1
    from company c
    where c.name = m.name
    and c.partner = m.partner 
    and c.id in (123,1122)
 )
```

Comment: @dneoth The query should retrieve the combination of **models and source** with id 1234, but not ids 123&1122.
Unfortunately, for this combination the above SQL's are not retrieving the right result, I already tried the second version you mentioned above before creating the final version  but looks like we are missing something there.
Thanks you all for your time in checking this.